# changing things in canvas by mouse movement using javaScript like size and location

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am just starting programming, and this is my second project—it's a paint app. I saw the project on YouTube and cloned it in my own way. However, when I encountered problems, I referred to the video, as beginners should. But the video didn't cover many features that were in my mind, **like how I could move things inside the canvas and change their size after clicking a button.**
this is my code

```
const canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const tools = document.querySelectorAll(".tool");
const fullColor = document.querySelector("#fill-color");
const brushSize = document.querySelector("#size-of-brush");
const colorBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".color .option");
const colorPicker = document.querySelector("#color-picker");
const clearCanvas = document.querySelector(".clear-canvas");
const saveCanvas = document.querySelector(".save-img");
// global variable
let method = "brush";
let draw = false;
let pervCorX;
let pervCorY;
let brushWidth = 5;
let oneDraw;
let color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";

//canvas width and height
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
});

// confirm mouse down and change  the color and size of brush and ships
const mousedown = (event) => {
  draw = true;
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  pervCorX = event.offsetX;
  pervCorY = event.offsetY;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = brushWidth;
  oneDraw = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

// witch shape and width is clicked
tools.forEach((toolsBtn) => {
  toolsBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    toolsBtn.classList.add("active");
    method = toolsBtn.id;
    // console.log(method);
  });
});

// confirmation of stooping drawing
const mouseup = () => {
  draw = false;
};

// drawing rectangle circle triangle
const rectangle = (event) => {
  const x = event.offsetX;
  const y = event.offsetY;
  const width = pervCorX - event.offsetX;
  const height = pervCorY - event.offsetY;
  if (fullColor.checked) return ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
};
const circle = (event) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  console.log("hihi");
  const width = pervCorX - event.offsetX;
  const height = pervCorY - event.offsetY;
  let radius = Math.sqrt(width ** 2 + height ** 2);
  ctx.arc(pervCorX, pervCorY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  if (fullColor.checked) return ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
};
const triangle = (event) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pervCorX, pervCorY);
  ctx.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
  ctx.lineTo(pervCorX * 2 - event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
  ctx.closePath();
  fullColor.checked ? ctx.fill() : ctx.stroke();
};

//checking what ship to draw
const startDrawing = (event) => {
  if (!draw) return;
  ctx.putImageData(oneDraw, 0, 0);

  if (method == "brush" || method == "eraser") {
    ctx.strokeStyle = method == "eraser" ? "#fff" : color;
    ctx.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
    ctx.stroke();
  } else if (method == "rectangle") {
    rectangle(event);
  } else if (method == "circle") {
    circle(event);
  } else if (method == "triangle") {
    triangle(event);
  }
};
colorBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  console.log(btn);
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".selected").classList.remove("selected");
    btn.classList.add("selected");
    color = window.getComputedStyle(btn).backgroundColor;
  });
});
//changing color of ships  and brush
colorPicker.addEventListener("change", () => {
  colorPicker.parentElement.style.background = colorPicker.value;
  colorPicker.parentElement.click();
});
// checking if mouse down in canvas and give brush size
brushSize.addEventListener("change", () => (brushWidth = brushSize.value));
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", startDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
//save and clear canvas
clearCanvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
saveCanvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  a.download = "canvas_image.png";
  a.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> like how I could move things inside the canvas and change their size after clicking a button

But this, I am assuming you are talking about features similar to what Figma/Adobe XD/etc have, where you draw a bunch of shapes and can then use your mouse/keyboard to move them.

For applications like these, you use the `Model View Controller (MVC)` architecture.

1. **Model** - reponsible for storing data. This can be stuff like coordinates and dimensions of shapes, fill, stroke, etc.
2. **View** - responsible for rendering object on your canvas. It reads the information about the objects from the model and draws it.
3. **Controller** - Responsible for handling user event. Based on events, updates the values in model and asks the view to redraw.

Over time, as you keep adding more features, your code design will get more complicated. This is where Object Oriented Programming comes in. You can explore how open source softwares are designed by going thorough their code on Github.

Here is a rough draft of how you might do it.

```js
// This is the model. It stores an array of objects.
// Each object contains information for rendering it.
// Notice how each type has different types of data.
const objectList = [
  { id: 0, type: 'rect', data: { x: 10, y: 5, w: 2, h: 4 } },
  { id: 1, type: 'circle', data: { x: 10, y: 5, r: 3.5 } },
  { id: 2, type: 'line', data: { x0: 10, y0: 5, x1: 2, y1: 4 } },
];

// This is the view. It basically renders everything in the objectList
const renderObjects = () => {
  objectList.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.type === 'rect') {
      // code to draw rectangle
    }
    if (obj.type === 'circle') {
      // code to draw rectangle
    }
    if (obj.type === 'line') {
      // code to draw rectangle
    }
  })
}

// Controllers
// These will be methods to modify items in objectList based on event handlers, etc.
const buttonEventHandler1 = (params) => {
  // ... update some item from objectList based on params.

  // redraw everything. Important for UI to update
  renderObjects();
}
const buttonEventHandler2 = (params) => {
  // ... update some item from objectList based on params.

  // redraw everything. Important for UI to update
  renderObjects();
}
```

You might even take this a step further by writing the `JSON.stringify(objectList)` to a file, and read a file to populate the initial values for `objectList`, just like paint applications.